# Referring to past times with "hence"

Tags: meaning-in-context, adverbs, tenses

From [Tor.com](http://www.tor.com/blogs/2011/06/pottermore-revealed), an interesting use of the word *hence*:

> Minutes ago, J.K. Rowling finally announced her plans behind Pottermore, the mysterious website that appeared **a week hence** with only a “Coming Soon” sign to warns readers and fans.

For me, the word *hence* can only be used to refer to times in the future, and the writer of the above quote should have used *ago*. However, *hence* is a pretty rare word, and it's possible that the past usage of *hence* is in fact standard, but I've never noticed it.

Is the past usage of *hence* sanctioned by any important authorities? Does it have a long tradition of usage? Or did the writer trip herself up trying to be fancy?

**Update**: The answers below all agree, but I'm looking for someone that can produce some actual evidence from usage or a respected authority. I've started a bounty with that in mind.

Comment: I think it was simply a solecism. The writer of the sentence thinks "hence" means in the past.

Comment: Given that the sentence in question has a typo in _warns_, I suspect no such authority will be found.

Comment: It looked OK to me at first with "hence" being used like the less common "thence", but when reading the whole thing including the "ago" at the beginning, it's definitely just plain wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Evidence from dictionaries:

[Hence](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/hence), when applied to time, is defined as:

> **2**. from this time; from now: *They will leave a month hence.*

There is not a shred of evidence in any dictionary or in common/traditional/standard usage that *hence* can be used to refer to the past.  So, as it is unsanctioned by any important authorities, and unused, I would say this is a case of either misconception or mistake on the writer's part.

In the quote, *ago* is the proper word to replace *hence* with.  It is possible that the writer confused *hence* with *since*, as *since* is sometimes used as a synonym of *ago*.

Comment: There is also not a shred of evidence from that definition that it *cannot* be used to refer to the past. *From now* can go in either direction, temporally.

Comment: @Jon: There my argument rests on the fact that _from now/from this time_ is never used for the past, either.  _Hence_ means _from now_, and neither _hence_ nor _from now_ are ever used for the past.  I am making use of the strongest argument available to me when I argue from silence.  The silence of dictionaries, and the silence of usage.  It's always much easier to prove a positive than a negative.

Comment: @drm65: I'll have to agree with @Jon, though rare. See what OED has to say, and the examples given therefrom. Hopefully @JSBangs will consider that *actual evidence from usage or a respected authority.*

Answer (score 6):

The definition and etymology show **hence** is meant to be a "future time"

I think it could be a typo for [thence](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/thence)

> from that time; thenceforth

Comment: Unfortunately _thence_ doesn't work in same way as _hence_.  "A week thence" is not a valid way of saying anything much.

Comment: @Rhodri: Yes, it is, it would mean 'from the announcement' rather than 'from the time of writing'. Pity that"minutes ago" proves that that's not what was meant.

Comment: @JoseK: Actually, though _a week thence_ does make sense per se, it does not fit in this context.  _...a week thence..._ - from what time?

Comment: @drm: I agree it's a mistaken use of hence in the article, my guess was if thence was from that time when the initial news of Pottermore broke - which was a week prior to it's actual launch

Comment: @JoseK: The only other mention of time in the quote was "Minutes ago..." With that as the only time antecedent, a week thence would only mean a week after minutes ago. There is no other way thence could possibly be used. I think it's obvious that the quote is saying that the mysterious website appeared a week ago, with only a "Coming Soon" message; and only minutes ago did Rowling announce her plans.

Answer (score 4):

*Garner's Modern American Usage* has the following entry on *hence*:

> This adverb has several meanings, listed here in decreasing order of frequency:
>
> 1. "for this reason;therefore" *your premise is flawed; hence, your argument fails*
> 2. "from this source" *she grew up in Colorado: hence her interest in mountain climbing*
> 3. "from this time; from now" *our anniversary is just two weeks hence*
> 4. "from this place; away" *the park is three miles hence*

It's clear, as others have noted, that the Tor.com writer mistakenly used *hence* in this third sense to describe something that occurred in the past. I wonder if the fourth use of *hence* might have led to this confusion. I assume that when *hence* is used spatially, as in the last example, that it can mean three miles in *any* direction and not imply a specific continued trajectory. If so, I can see someone applying this same logic temporally and referring to an incident as occurring a week *away from this point in time* in either direction, past or future—particularly if that person was a time traveller.

Answer (score 3):

I found [this source](http://www.hydroponicsearch.com/spelling/simplesearch.php), which cites the 1913 edition of Webster's Revised Unabridged Dictionary via [The Collaborative International Dictionary of English v.0.48](http://www.dict.org/bin/Dict).  Emphasis added by me.

> `2. From this time; **in the future**; as, a week hence. "Half an
>         hour hence." --Shak.
>   [1913 Webster]

This is the only source I've found that specifically states that the time is in the future.  It seems even the [source word](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=hence&searchmode=none) was ambiguous, meaning only "away from here" without specifying any (other) sort of directionality that might give us a clue.

Edit: I also have a notion about the time direction that is likely unprovable. *Hence* can also be used to mean something like "therefore."  For instance, I ate garlic this morning hence the bad breath.  In this sense, *hence* introduces the condition that follows the past event, so *hence* is associated with future time.  Perhaps more clearly, *hence* moves us away from a point in the past (eating garlic) toward the present/future (having bad breath). Thus the arrow points forward in time, not backward.

Answer (score 3):

The use of hence referring to past times is obscure and rare as mentioned in [OED](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxford_English_Dictionary).

From OED via library online service (which I unfortunately can't link because it required my library card):

> hence, *adv.*
>
> **II.** Of time.
>
> **4.a.** From this time onward, henceforward, henceforth. Also with *from* (†*fro*). *arch.* and *poet.*

but

> **4.†b.** (At some time in the past reckoned) from now; in quot. 1393 = since, ago. *Obs. rare.*
>
> 1393    [*Langland Piers Plowman*](http://quod.lib.umich.edu/c/cme/PPlLan/1:1?rgn=div1;view=fulltext;rgn1=author;q1=Langland) C. vi. 35   Whanne ich ȝong was‥meny ȝer hennes.
>
> 1610    Bp. J. Hall *Common Apol. against Brownists* xiii. 34   But you leape backe‥from hence to the Apostles times.

Answer (score 2):

I have never heard of it being used to indicate a time in the past and can't find any support for it. I also agree it's simply a mistake.

It's possible that "since" was meant; I can't say I'm certain that it's correct usage, but I have seen it used to mean "ago".

Comment: "Since" meaning "ago" is alive and well in Yorkshire, but it is archaic in standard Englishes. I agree with Robusto that the author was looking for a word meaning a relative "ago" and thought that "hence" would do.

Comment: @ColinFine: Hmm... is it really so rare outside Yorkshire? I think I've heard it occasionally. // Wherever I heard it, I think I interpreted it as "they buried her [and it's now] two weeks since [then]".

Comment: @Cerberus: I've no doubt it goes beyond Yorkshire, but I don't know how widely. I would regard it as archaic in general use (indeed, when W. S. Gilbert wrote in *Ruddigore* in the 1880's "He died ten years since" I believe it was deliberately archaic or rustic).

Comment: @ColinFine: Yes it doesn't sound standard to me; I remember my confusion when I first heard it (it must have been long since). *Rustic* sounds appropriate (I'd never have guessed Yorkshire, but something provincial, yes).

Comment: @ColinFine et al., I have to disagree. *A week since* is perfectly standard English. At least here, on the East Coast of the US, I here it in practical if not frequent use. *Ago* is certainly preferred.

Answer (score 0):

"Hence" has more usages than just "from this/that time"; it is also used to point to the source or origin of something.

E.g. "Bill issued hence" means "Bill came out from *there*", where *there* is pointing to an antecedent in a previous clause or statement.

If you want to be clear that the meaning is "from this/that time", use "henceforth", which has drifted into being used only for time (when it's used at all).

Comment: I think there's a confusion betwen *hence* and *thence*: *hence* means 'from here' (and extensions): *thence* is 'from there'.

Answer (score 0):

> Five hundred years ago I would have made all
>   England such an England as neither Dane, Saxon, nor
>   Norman should have conquered. Five hundred years
>   hence I should have been such a counsellor to Kings as
>   the world hath never dreamed of.

Kipling, *Puck of Pooks's Hill*.

Not exactly proof, but evidence that Kipling, at least, used *hence* for the future only (and meaning 'from here', not 'from some other point').

Answer (score -1):

I would agree on the ago. the [NGram Viewer](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=a+week+hence&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) seems to do as well - here is the usage by the way

[NGRAM http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/chart?content=a%20week%20hence&corpus=0&smoothing=3&year_start=1800&year_end=2000](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/chart?content=a%20week%20hence&corpus=0&smoothing=3&year_start=1800&year_end=2000)

Comment: How does that NGram support any particular usage? Isn't it just tracking uses of "a week hence"? How would it know if that _hence_ was for the future or not?

Comment: It does not. It shows that it is getting to be more and more archaic to use it, _hence_ the danger of abusing it ;)