# "Thence" to allude to the past

Tags: adverbs, tenses, time

I see that **"hence"** means roughly "[from *this* fact/time/place/source](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/hence)", while **"thence"** means roughly "[from *that* fact/time/place/source](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/thence)".

Usage such as "[half an hour hence](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/34497/22525)" is typically (although perhaps not universally) used to refer to times in the future, being taken as "from this time" or "[forward] from now".

Would it thus be correct to say, e.g., "[today] is three years *thence*" — in the sense of "from *that* time" or "[forward] from *then*" — in order to allude to the day three years ago?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that while as per its definition it is correct to use *thence* in the way you suggest ('... three years thence ...') this is not a common usage. It is certainly more commonly seen when referring to *place* rather than *time*:

> I drove from LA to Reno, thence to Las Vegas.

Consider also the related term *thenceforth*, meaning 'from that time on' (and compare with *henceforth*: 'from *this* time on'):

> I didn't make a hit all season and was thenceforth known as Strikeout Steve.

Comment: Oh, I'm sure such usage isn't at all common.  But it does appear to be [non-zero](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+week+hence%2Ca+week+thence&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) historically.

Comment: Absolutely @TimParenti, I agree it's valid, a Google search on 'years hence' produces a bunch of hits. Not common is what I said, and I certainly don't recall having seen or heard it in my lifetime as an Australian English speaker.